# Android Relative Layouts with ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm using a ListView with a RelativeLayout for each of the Items in it. I can display the avatar, title and text info correctly but I can not get the time_stamp to sit on the same line as the title. So the avatar is on the left, title on top with the timestamp to the far right along the same line and the text_info directly underneath.

Layout is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />


    <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            />

    <TextView    
            android:id="@+id/time_stamp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_title"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_info"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `time_stamp` TextView, use `layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `layout_alignTop` set to the title TextView. So it will be on the right of the list and top will be aligned with title.